# How to copy a row of 2D Vector to a 1D vector?

Tags: c++, vector

How should I initialize copyRow with first row of holder_node?
I came up with the following code.

```
vector<vector<double>> holder_node;
vector<double> copyRow(initial_values[0].begin(), initial_values[0].end());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access an element of a vector (even if the element again is a `vector`) through array subscription / through an index:

```
vector<double> copyRow = holder_node[0];
```

Note that a vector is not just a pointer to some memory; it can distinguish copying from moving and behaves correctly in each case. Above statement triggers a copy.

Comment: A note to those that follow: This works because `vector<vector<double>>` is not a 2D `vector`. It's a `vector` of `vector`s. Stephan's answer copies one of the inner `vector`s (the first one in this case) by using it as the argument for the `vector` copy constructor.

Comment: Is there a way to have the holder_node resize itself? like after inserting one row I just want the holder_node to have one row. How do I have it so that after initializing the elements in the holder_node is resized?

Comment: @NoobCoder to resize a std::vector take a look at [std::vector::resize](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize)

Comment: A vector adapts it's size whenever you append items (e.g. by using `push_back`) automatically

Comment: @Stephan Lechner how would I use`push_back` for 2D vectors instead of having to do `holder_node[0][0] = value;`?

Comment: @NoobCoder If you start from an empty `holder_node`, then add a element to it, you will have one "row". If what you added was a one element `vector<double> { value }`, then you have one "row" and one "column"